# Bind9 Servfail, unknown host

Tags: dns

I'm new to bind9. I've fixed a lot of issues, but now I need some help.

I basically just want to bind my domain magestionfacile.fr and some subdomains to 94.23.108.206.

Here's my configuration files:

**named.conf.local**

```
zone "magestionfacile.fr" {
        type master;
        allow-transfer {94.23.108.206;};
        file "/etc/bind/db.magestionfacile.fr";
};
```

**db.magestionfacile.fr**

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for broadcast zone
;

; Time To Live
$TTL    604800

; General Informations
@       IN      SOA     magestionfacile.fr. root.magestionfacile.fr. (
                             10         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL

; Domain        TTL     IN      Type    Value
                        IN      NS      ns354747.ovh.net.
                        IN      NS      sdns1.ovh.net.
                        IN      NS      sdns2.ovh.net.

@                       IN      A       94.23.108.206
vmx                     IN      A       94.23.108.206

vimexcom                IN      CNAME   vmx.magestionfacile.fr.

ownercheck                      IN      TXT     "some_number"
```

The three NS directives, I'm not sure if it's the right values. I mean, I'm not even sure if only one DNS server is sufficient so...

**Some tests:**

```
odoo@yann-acer-portable:~$ nslookup magestionfacile.fr 8.8.8.8
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   magestionfacile.fr
Address: 94.23.108.206

odoo@yann-acer-portable:~$ nslookup magestionfacile.fr
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

** server can't find magestionfacile.fr: SERVFAIL

odoo@yann-acer-portable:~$ ping magestionfacile.fr
ping: unknown host magestionfacile.fr
odoo@yann-acer-portable:~$ ping vmx.magestionfacile.fr
ping: unknown host vmx.magestionfacile.fr
```

I'm aware that usually, you need two DNS servers, right ? Can I do with one ? Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

SERVFAIL means that the nameserver for one reason or another could not produce a valid answer to the question. For more information, you need to look in the nameserver log file (although if what you posted up there is the entire zone file, the problem likely is a missing $ORIGIN).

Comment: Okay, here's the situation: my site is hosted on the ovh servers, on a virtual server. My url (magestionfacile.fr) is provided by phpnet. Do I need to set myself a nameserver ? I'm relatively new to that so must of what I know is from bits readed here and there.